# How do I have Angular 2 pick up changes added by React?

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular-material2

I am using Angular2 and react together. To do this I have the following TSX file....

```
export class ReactDataGridComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(
        private el:ElementRef,
        @Inject("Window") private window: Window,
        private lib: LibraryService,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    rowGetter(i) {
        return this.lib.data.datasets[i];
    }

    render(){
        ReactDOM.render(
            <ReactDataGrid
                minHeight={this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight}
                columns={this.lib.data.headers}
                rowGetter={this.rowGetter.bind(this)}
                rowsCount={this.lib.data.datasets.length}
            />,
            this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML
        );
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.window.onresize = this.render.bind(this);
        this.lib.resetSubject.subscribe(()=>{
            this.render();
        })
        this.lib.getLibrarySummaryItems();
    }
}
```

This works but if React renders say the Angular Material Components....

```
<div fxFlex> <md-icon>home</md-icon> </div>
```

Angular doesn't handle the directive and component. Is there a way that I can tell angular to rewire the components once this change happens?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using angular2 and react together? I don't really understand your question. What change is not picked up by angular?

Comment: Mainly because there is a control written in react that I don't want to have to reinvent. Also it may com in handy in some data intensive situations (although I haven't really tested that theory so I can't say for sure)